# How to add a button to actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have tried adding it by looking at various guides and stackOverflow topics, but they didn't help. I do everything as various guides say, but I am still unable to get settings icon at the action bar. MainActivity.class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.entry_test, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    return true;
}
```

entry_test.xml (this is where the icon is):

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_cart"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:title="Settings"
/>

</menu>
```

The icon is not displayed in the action bar and when pressing "more" button (or whatever it is called), a button appears at the bottom saying Settings (title of it). Thats it.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove the `orderInCategory`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using an ActionBar via the support library, try the following:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Settings" />

</menu>
```